# How to combine two sql queries in one controller action in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net mvc application, I have to fetch information about a page from two separate tables.

The queries are something like these:

```
string query = "select * from some_table1; select * from some_table2;"
```

Then the information from the tables is extracted using:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString'))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  con.Open();
  using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while(reader.Read())
    {
      // do the addition of data into a model
    }
  }
}
```

Do I have to parse / read the data twice to populate the data inside two different models. Or can it be done in one parse?

Thanks

Comment: If you have 2 different field sets from your queries - yes you should populate data twice

Comment: Thanks a lot @teovankot

Comment: "select * from some_table1 `UNION` select * from some_table2;" could be used to combine the result of both the queries than just read it

Comment: Hi @MohitShrivastava, the union only works only when you have the same number of columns in both the table and their data types are same respectively. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to get data by joining the tables you could have single model. Make it a single query by introducing the join.

If they are different datasets altogether, then you need two queries. If you are worried about opening/closing of two connections, you need not have to do it. Make use of `CommandText`

```
// Create the first command and execute
var command = new SqlCommand("<SQL Command>", connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Change the SQL Command and execute
command.CommandText = "<New SQL Command>";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hi @Vinoth. I used this approach finally. Writing out two separate queries and reading the data but with a single open sql connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to just use on parse for each table. That way, if you need that info for a different method you can just call the same parse again without having to duplicated code, make it overly complicated or put a bigger load then necessary on your database.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to create two class for both the tables :

For example :

```
       public class Table1
       {
          public string col1{get;set;}//set the properties

       }

       public class Table2
       {
        public string col1{get;set;}//set the properties

       }
     public class CombileResult
     {
         public Table1 objtable1{get;set;}
         public Table2 objtable2{get;set;}
      }


    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString'))
        {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
          con.Open();
          using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
            CombileResult objCombine=new objCombine();
             objCombine.objtable1=//content for table 1
             objCombine.objtable2=//content for table 2
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the entity framework to use/access multiple database table then make the model class accordingly.

Comment: Hi @darpan_systematix, I have used entity framework elsewhere in the code, but in this example, I am performing specific queries (which are also changing continuously), hence I can't use entity framework to perform the task. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

**controller**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT TOP 10 ContactName, City, Country FROM Customers;";
        query += "SELECT TOP 10 (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) EmployeeName, City, Country FROM Employees";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        gvCustomers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        gvCustomers.DataBind();
                        gvEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
                        gvEmployees.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<div ID="gvCustomers" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Employee Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Result:**

[image]